# Is SVM (support vector machine) iterative?

Tags: loss, support-vector-machine

**a** - First I want to understand in a simple (1D or 2d case **without any kernel tricks**) whether the process of fitting the best-separating line is iterative just like in Neural Networks with some loss function while the separating line's parameters are adjusted till we get the best fitting results.
Or maybe it is more like in the linear regression case, where of course I can iterate to find the best-fitted line, but there is no need to since in the case of linear regression there is a straightforward equation that returns me the slope, and the intercept of the best-fitted line while in the input are the coordinates of all observation points.

Another part of the question is regarding the famous Kernel trick (guess and maybe the answer relates to the first part of the question asked above):

**b** -  Is the process of curving the space with observations iterative or not? After all, there is an infinite number of variations one can curve the plane with observations.

Thank you very much

Comment: How can you curve a XOR function within a 2-d plane to become linearly separable?

Comment: If you have initially your data in 2d the kernel trick puts the data on a curved 2d plane in 3d space and cuts this  curved 2d plane with noncurved - linear 2d plane in 3d space
I have asked why this is better (or not?) then leaving the data in 2d space and curve the cutting plane to be curved 2d surface in 3d space that cuts the data remainig on a flat 3d plane in 3d space

Comment: Please, split this post into multiple ones, one for each question.